# How to pass one ID parameter in a scalar function inside a Select block using IN statement in #temp_table

Tags: function, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameters

I've written a simple stored procedure which uses a scalar function for 4 of the selected data.

I pass an ID which is part of the hole select as parameter of this function.

And finally that stored procedure is matching if ids are `IN` a `Temp_Table` I've created at the beginning of the stored procedure.

Problem : the stored procedure is running into an infinite loop.

I know the problem surely comes from the multiple parameter passe as Id in the function but I don't get the logic here !

I tried testing seperately and got the results as expected.

Here is the stored procedure:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE GetBordereauCotisations
    @annee INT,
    @sectionId INT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --Creation table temporaire pour stocker les adhérents d'une section
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#table_adherent_ids', 'U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #table_adherent_ids; 

    CREATE TABLE #table_adherent_ids (AdherentId INT);

    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #table_adherent_ids 
            SELECT p.RessourceId
            FROM Personnes p
            INNER JOIN PersonneAdherentSituations ps ON ps.RessourceId = p.RessourceId
            WHERE p.SectionId = @sectionId AND ps.StatutAdhesion = 880
    END

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        pas.NumeroAdherent AS NumAdherent,
        CONCAT(ppi.Nom, ' ', ppi.Prenom) AS NomPrenom,
        si.Numero AS CodeSection,
        'CodeTarif?' AS CodeTarif,
        dbo.GetCodeTarifByTrimestrePaye(pas.RessourceId, @annee, 1) AS T1,
        dbo.GetCodeTarifByTrimestrePaye(pas.RessourceId, @annee, 2) AS T2,
        dbo.GetCodeTarifByTrimestrePaye(pas.RessourceId, @annee, 3) AS T3,
        dbo.GetCodeTarifByTrimestrePaye(pas.RessourceId, @annee, 4) AS T4
    FROM
        PersonneAdherentSituations pas
    INNER JOIN 
        PersonnePersoIdentites ppi ON pas.RessourceId = ppi.RessourceId
    INNER JOIN 
        SectionIdentifications si ON si.RessourceId = @sectionId
    INNER JOIN 
        PersonneAdherentFinancesVersements pfv ON pfv.SectionNumero = si.Numero
    WHERE 
        YEAR(pfv.[Date]) = @annee
    GROUP BY 
        pas.NumeroAdherent, ppi.Nom, ppi.Prenom, si.Numero, pas.RessourceId
    HAVING 
        pas.RessourceId IN (SELECT tai.AdherentId FROM #table_adherent_ids tai)

    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE #table_adherent_ids;
    END
END
GO
```

Here is the function:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION GetCodeTarifByTrimestrePaye
    (@adhrentId INT,
     @annee INT,
     @trimestre INT)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @codeTarif nvarchar (MAX);
    DECLARE @rowsSelected int = (SELECT CASE 
                                    WHEN @trimestre = 1 THEN 1
                                    ELSE @trimestre - 1 END)
    DECLARE @apayerAnnee int = (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(pfv.Apayer, 1, 4)))
                            FROM PersonneAdherentFinancesVersements pfv
                            WHERE YEAR(pfv.[Date]) = @annee
                            AND pfv.RessourceId = @adhrentId)
    DECLARE @apayerTrimestre int = (SELECT MAX(CONVERT(int, SUBSTRING(pfv.Apayer, 7, 1)))
                                    FROM PersonneAdherentFinancesVersements pfv
                                    WHERE YEAR(pfv.[Date]) = @annee
                                    AND pfv.RessourceId = @adhrentId)

    SET @codeTarif = (SELECT CASE 
                        WHEN @annee < @apayerAnnee 
                            THEN l.Texte
                        WHEN @annee = @apayerAnnee AND @trimestre <= @apayerTrimestre
                            THEN l.Texte
                        ELSE
                            ''
                        END
                    FROM PersonneAdherentFinancesVersements pfv
                    INNER JOIN ListeStatique l ON l.Id = pfv.CodeTarifId
                    WHERE pfv.IsValidated = 1 
                    AND pfv.ValideParFede = 1
                    AND pfv.RessourceId = @adhrentId
                    ORDER BY l.Texte
                    OFFSET @rowsSelected ROWS
                    FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY)

    RETURN @codeTarif;
END
GO
```

How could I obtain only one expected result using my scalar function?

Comment: There are no loops in your code. If you run it and it never completes, that means your query is very slow.

Comment: Txh @GSerg I know it's not a loop like infite it was a way to show what's happening. The charge ogf the SP is not so bad so I don't get why the SP never gets to the end !

Comment: Actally it looks likes a real non tuned SP. I know where the whieigt is. I'm gonna correct it and Edit.